# Resource file not found in Java program

Tags: java

I have tried every path that I could and it is unable to find the file path.

```
public class JobOrderGenerator {

    private File file = new File("/resources/Shop-Order.xlsx");
    private int sheetNumber = 0;

    public JobOrderGenerator(List<ShopOrder> shopOrder) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {

        for (ShopOrder shopOrder1 : shopOrder) {

            writeToSpecificCell(2, 1, sheetNumber, shopOrder1.getPo_number()); //Po Number
            writeToSpecificCell(7, 3, sheetNumber, shopOrder1.getPo_number()); //Part Number
            LocalDate date = shopOrder1.getPo_due_date();
            String dateToString = date.toString();
            writeToSpecificCell(1, 2, sheetNumber, dateToString); //Due_Date
            writeToSpecificCell(7, 5, sheetNumber, Integer.toString(shopOrder1.getPart_quantity())); //Quantity
            //writeToSpecificCell(1,2,sheetNumber, shopOrder.get); //Material
            writeToSpecificCell(8, 3, sheetNumber, shopOrder1.getPart_decription()); //Part Description
            //writeToSpecificCell(1,2,sheetNumber, shopOrder.getCustomer()); //Customer
            writeToSpecificCell(10, 1, sheetNumber, shopOrder1.getMachine_number()); //Machine

            sheetNumber++;

        }
    }

    void writeToSpecificCell(int rowNumber, int cellNumber, int sheetNumber, String value) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {

        if(file.exists()){
            System.out.println("Was was found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("File was NOT found");
        }
```

[image: File is in the resources folder]

Whenever I run the program the else statement runs saying

"File was NOT found"

Advice?

Comment: How you are getting the file?

Comment: @Arpit I click on the file in intellji, get its path and take out a / symbol or word each each time it fails but it continued to not find it.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Looks like there was a whitespace between `Shop-Order` and `.xslx` in the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the `File` directly referring it's path. Instead you should get it using `Classloader`.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("Shop-Order.xlsx").getFile());
```

And if you want to load the `File` in a static way, the you have to tweak the code little bit as `getClass()` method being non-static method can not be called from static method or block.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = JobOrderGenerator.class.getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("Shop-Order.xlsx").getFile());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `File file = new File("/resources/Shop-Order.xlsx")` the JVM looks for the file in the local file system. Since you've put the excel file in resources (which is deployed in the jar), you need to get it from the classpath. 
Try this:

```
File file = new File(JobOrderGenerator.class.getResource("Shop-Order.xlsx").toURI());
```

Also, like @dhh mentioned in the comments - you have a whitespace in the file name.